# After login redirect to previous page

Tags: magento-1.9

After login redirect to previous page all page it's working fine but i am using custom url for shopping cart page so it redirect to my account page. How to fix it

```
<div class="Login_cart">
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                        <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
                        <?php
                        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
                        $cusname = $customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname();
                        $name = substr($cusname,0,18)."..";
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account'); ?>"><?php echo "Hi "."$name"  ?> &nbsp;</a>
                            <ul  class="subaccount">
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account'); ?>">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>">Order</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('wishlist'); ?>">Wishlist</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('newsletter/manage'); ?>">Newsletter</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('review/customer'); ?>">Review</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>">Login / Register</a>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Describe your problem in detail.

Comment: i added above code in shopping cart page, after login it redirect to My account. If I use magento default top link (login) it redirect to previous page

Comment: where i can't understand sorry

Comment: <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account'); ?> change to <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(''); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please simply change the following in your code.

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account'); ?>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(''); ?>
```

Also, I believe all of this is irrelevant as it pertains to account area.  You can try removing it and test:

```
                    <ul  class="subaccount">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account'); ?>">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>">Order</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('wishlist'); ?>">Wishlist</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('newsletter/manage'); ?>">Newsletter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('review/customer'); ?>">Review</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
```